Does Section 31 no longer exist in the 32nd century?
I am currently watching the latest and final season of Star Trek: Discovery. The premier season 5 episode is titled and introduces 'The Red Directive' into canon, which seems to indicate that certain Federation Captains and crews get classified missions that take absolute precedence. During the episode, Dr. Kovich, an A.I. specialist and possible Federation Commodore, encourages the Discovery crew to finish the mission at almost any cost.
In previous eras of Star Trek such clandescent classified missions would have mostly been assigned to Section 31. So my question is, does Section 31 not exist in this era, and do viewers know why? Or is there something I missed?

I didn't watched this season yet, but my best guess would clearly be that they hide even deeper now wink wink

Without spoiling, the "thing" they are investigating/after is something that IMO would be of the deepest most importance to all of Star Trek.

AFAIK, Section 31 is never mentioned once Discovery hits the future. Given the "reduced" nature of the Federation in the 32nd century it seems unlikely that S31 still exists. The Section 31 movie might answer this in the future, say early 2025.

That said, this (unsourced and unreferenced) site indicates that S31 does still exist.

@Paulie_D that is very likely answer. And given the that not only is Discovery picking up a TNG unfinished plot, it also is paralleling/referencing subject matter from Picard S1, which also shares a bend with Disco Season 2 with both featuring "Control" (which was allegedly fully dismantled), so maybe everything will tie into itself and Section 31 film, but just in case stated somewhere I missed, I thought I would ask anyways.

Dr. Kovich has this air of mystery about him that could indicate his involvement with Section 31. Or he could be an artificial life form. Or just an eccentric old doctor. Maybe even a plain, simple tailor in his younger days. Could be anything.

@JesseC.Slicer Ya, I agree. I keep expecting him to be linked to something beyond what we have been told. Section 31 is a good guess, but I also half expect Control to rear its head again...
